# Regex match last occurrence of all characters between two strings

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to extract the torrent name from torrent files.
Without looking to deep in how torrent files are structured I noticed that I only need to match last occurrence of all characters between two strings which in my case are `:` * `12:piece lengthi`.

Here is the beginning of Arch Linux iso torrent file:

```
d8:announce42:http://tracker.archlinux.org:6969/announce7:comment41:Arch Linux 2015.07.01 (www.archlinux.org)10:created by13:mktorrent 1.013:creation datei1435770645e4:infod6:lengthi677380096e4:name29:archlinux-2015.07.01-dual.iso12:piece lengthi
```

I need to extract `archlinux-2015.07.01-dual.iso` witch is in between `:` and `12:piece lengthi`. I checked this pattern with other torrent files in my case it will work! I can't figure out how to combine the regex `(?<=:)(.*)(?=12:piece lengthi)` and `:(?:.(?!:))+$` if they are even correct at all.

I'm trying to make a bash script with `grep` OR `awk` OR `sed` or something that could with a linux command.

**Final perfectly working solution (thoroughly tested):
This works with all types of non-standard characters for example Cyrillic**.

```
torrent_title=$(tr -d "\n" < "$filename" | iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 -c | sed 's/.*:\(.*\)12:piece lengthi.*/\1/')
```

<strike>Update:All suggestion work but Torrent files are binary files for example I tried `grep --text` and `strings file |` piped to grep or sed but random strings from the binary file are messing up the output.</strike>

Update 2 and SOLVED IT: so the final command is this

`head -1 file.torrent| strings | tr -d "\n\r" | iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 -c| sed 's/.*:\(.*\)12:piece lengthi.*/\1/`

I figured that the info is only in the first line of the file.
In my original example post I forgot to copy a couple of more strings at the end

```
 d8:announce42:http://tracker.archlinux.org:6969/announce7:comment41:Arch Linux 2015.07.01 (www.archlinux.org)10:created by13:mktorrent 1.013:creation datei1435770645e4:infod6:lengthi677380096e4:name29:archlinux-2015.07.01-dual.iso12:piece lengthi524288e6:pieces25840:
```

witch are part of the first line so for that I needed to slightly change hek2mgl sed
 answer.

Update 3 The right way to do it is to use a parser, I learned it the hard way.

Comment: There have to be tools that let you inspect a torrent file that you can use for this more properly? That being said that appears to be a set of `length:value` pairs so you might do better to actually just parse it. (Though your rough splitting will also work.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `sed` for that, like this:

```
sed 's/.*:\(.*\)12:piece lengthi/\1/' input.torrent
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this with GNU grep:

```
 grep -oP ':\K[^:]*(?=12:piece lengthi$)' file
```

Output:

```
archlinux-2015.07.01-dual.iso
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 sed -e 's/12:piece lengthi//' -e 's/.*://'
```